# Does a dbt macro using {% if execute %} always need an else statement?

Tags: python, jinja2, dbt

I'm writing a macro in dbt using jinja as follows:

```
{% if execute %}
  {% set parameters = results.columns[0].values() %}
{% else %}
  {% set parameters = [] %}
{% endif %}
```

My question is, should I include the else statement even if it runs without it? My model compiles and runs when I remove lines 3 and 4, but philosophically I thought every "if" statement should have an escape. Is that not the case?

I tried removing the if statement altogether and running only

{% set parameters = results.columns[0].values() %}

And that returned the error "'None' has no attribute 'table'".

Answer (score 1):

An else branch is not required. When you have an if-statement without an else branch, it will simply do nothing if the statement is false.

If it helps, you can think of this as an implicit else branch (which will 'set' parameters to be undefined)

The error you are getting tells you an `if execute` is required. It occurs when DBT needs to execute some SQL to compile your models; this will generally fail because DBT normally compiles all models before execution, but `if execute` exists to allow you to defer compilation to the point of execution.